# prevent result, show through AJAX, after reload browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a insert query through ajax. It is working correctly. But when I reload browser then result disappears from div section and if I insert form through ajax again then result is showing.

I have a file **first.php** (in which, form is present), a AJAX code and a **firstcall.php** where query will be execute.

My **first.php** (html form) is:

```
<form  class="reservation-form mb-0" action="" method="post"  autocomplete="off">
<input name="name1" id="name1" class="form-control"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" required aria-required="true">
<input name="age" id="age" class="form-control" required  type="number" placeholder="Enter Age" aria-required="true">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="namec[]" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" >
<input type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-warning" value="Submit" id="submit">
 </form>
```

Here data should be display:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
 <div class="panel panel-primary" id="showdata">
<!-- Here is the results, but when reload browser then result disapper-->    
</div>      
</div>
```

AJAX is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    var name1 = $("#name1").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();

    var chkArray=[];
    $('.checkbox1:checked').each( function() {               
    chkArray.push($(this).val());    
    } );
    var selected;
    selected = chkArray.join(',') ;

    if(selected.length > 1){
    $.ajax( {
    url:'firstcall.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{name1: name1,age: age,namec: chkArray},
     }).done(function(data){
      $("#showdata").html(data);
         });

        }
            else{
    alert("Please at least one of the checkbox");   
 }
 });    
 });

</script>
```

**firstcall.php** is:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" id="showdata">
<?php 
foreach($_POST['namec'] as $selected){
echo $selected;
$_SESSION['name1']=$_POST["name1"];
$_SESSION['age']=$_POST["age"];

echo $name1=$_SESSION['name1'];
echo $age=$_SESSION['age'];

$query=mysql_query("insert into patient_details (p_name,p_age,g_number) values ('$name1','$age','$selected')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Thanks for reply..Result disappeared, when I reload manually browser

Comment: <div class="panel panel-primary" id="showdata">
    
</div>

Comment: That's what happens with ajax - it's client side only, if you want the reasults to stay, you will need to stick them in a session var and output them in first.php if the var exists

Comment: Means in firstcall.php, make variable in session and after that in first.php if(isset($_SESSION['fef'])){.....same query will execute....}

Comment: I wouldn't execute the query again - just session the results, otherwise if the user refreshes the page loads, you will get an insert everytime they refresh the page (unless you want that to happen?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163715/discussion-between-vinod-jaiswal-and-pete).

Comment: I tried, but it is showing 2 times result after click button

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the Ajax result to also show on page load?

Right now you only execute the JS after a click (so on page load/relaod you will just see the html), you might want to execute it after page load aswell (so execute the script without the .click)

You could create a function once, and call it when the page is ready and on click.

Comment: Thank you for reply..means same query one more time within div section

Comment: Yep, altohough you could also do what Boian Ivanov says. Whatever you prefer. But changing your mysql to mysqli has to be done either way, mysql is depricated.

Comment: But when if  after ajax call then query will run again and it will insert same thing?

Comment: Yes, though this way you will be doing two requests, one the main for the full page, and one after load to get the second part. For simple things like this I would recommend just simply serve the content when loading the page.

Comment: Can we join chat room?

Answer (score 0):

First of all fix your query to use MySQLi, instead of MySQL, check [this](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) or the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
Also don't ever add direct $_POST or $_GET variables into your mysql query, filter them first using mysqli_real_escape.

```
$name1 = mysqli_real_escape($link, $_POST["name1"]);
$age = mysqli_real_escape($link, $_POST["age"]);
```

After that, to show the data when the page reloads, you need to load the data with the page, easiest way to do that is just add in your HTML PHP tags with an echo command inside, adding your variables.